# mysql date comparison using timestamp retuns wrong answer

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying get data from MySQL using date between 2015 February 2 ,starting to  ending  using this query but MySQL returns all rows in February

```
SELECT CustomerID, 
    CustomerName, 
    DATE, 
    Doller,
    Minute ,
    Rate,Total, 
    NULL AS Amountofpaying
FROM saletrack where CustomerID=1
UNION ALL 
SELECT CustomerID, 
    CustomerName, 
    DATE, 
    NULL AS Doller,
    NULL AS Minute, 
    NULL AS Rate, 
    NULL AS Total, 
    Amountofpaying
FROM paymentdetails 
where CustomerID=1 and  `date` BETWEEN '2015-02-02 00:00:01' AND '2015-02-02 23:59:59'
ORDER BY DATE
```

please look images I commented below

Comment: please click the link to view image of my table [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/U7Xcb.png

Comment: What is the type of `date`?  Please provide some sample data.

Comment: its a timestamp  please check image  or  2015-01-30 23:44:11

Comment: I think those rows are coming from `saletrack` not `paymentdetails`.  You need to add the condition to the first `select`.

Comment: how ? i dont know it and also i joined them :(

Comment: i want answer from both table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the timestamp condition in the select from saletrack:

```
SELECT CustomerID, 
    CustomerName, 
    DATE, 
    Doller,
    Minute ,
    Rate,Total, 
    NULL AS Amountofpaying
FROM saletrack where CustomerID=1 and `date` BETWEEN '2015-02-02 00:00:01' AND '2015-02-02 23:59:59'
UNION ALL 
SELECT CustomerID, 
    CustomerName, 
    DATE, 
    NULL AS Doller,
    NULL AS Minute, 
    NULL AS Rate, 
    NULL AS Total, 
    Amountofpaying
FROM paymentdetails 
where CustomerID=1 and  `date` BETWEEN '2015-02-02 00:00:01' AND '2015-02-02 23:59:59'
ORDER BY DATE
```